# Looking for real time collaborative diagram drawing tool

Tags: software-rec, diagrams, drawing

I have seen a number of diagram software packages but most don't support real time collaboration. Google docs Drawing does the real-time collaboration, but is severely limited on features--focused on drawing rather than diagrams. I want something that supports connectors with flexible routing and such. Mind maps would be also be nice but would be a secondary requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=real+time+collaboration+diagram) pointed me to [Cacoo](http://cacoo.com/).
I have never used it but I just watched the demo video they have on their home page.

The collaboration aspect seems to work just like Google Docs and it seems like it has many features.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for the response! I took a look at Cacoo and as far as I can tell, it's connector support is minimal. I was hoping there would be something better out there...

Comment: Fair enough. You could edit your question and explain what kind of diagram you wish to draw. Maybe mention what connectors you're looking for. You may get more answers that way.

I'm sure someone out there has wanted to draw the same.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *develop* an application like this, take a look at [Dawn](http://www.mftech.org/dawn/). It already does a lot of the ugly collaboration stuff - but you'll have to define the structure of diagrams yourself.

Other than that - how about using whatever non-collaborative drawing tool you like best in combination with NetViewer, TeamViewer or any other of the conferencing tools available?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I didn't really want to create one. I'm really surprised there isn't something better out there.

As for something like TeamViewer, that would be a nuisance, but... I guess might work for some cases.